# Display YUY2 (Y'UV422) using OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es, qt5

I have an video stream in frames of YUY2 pixel format and I'd like to display it to the user. If I were to display it in Qt5's QLable, I'd need to convert it to RGB first, which is quite slow (unless you use ffmpeg/libav family of libraries, I suppose).

So I thought that it would be a lot faster to use OpenGL/OpenGLES to do the GPU-accelerated conversion to RGB24/RGB32 (if it's even needed) and display that. But how do I do that? As I understand, it's not so easy to write, especially for someone not too familiar with OpenGL, shaders and textures. You can assume I have a `char* pixelData` and `size_t bytes, width, height`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is to use 3 textures, 1 (full res) for the Y component and 2 (half width) for the Cb and Cr.

Then you write a fragment shader that samples all the 3 textures at the same normalized coordinate, and use the matrix [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) to convert from YUV to RGB.